# What is the difference between benign and malicious javascript(both obfuscated)

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am now doing a research on this so just would like to know

Is there any visible difference between benign and malicious javascript(both got obfuscated already)?

I had a glimpse of some formal websites and noticed they also obfuscated their source code for security purpose but, it seems that there are actually some kinds of differences existing.

Anyone can give some tips and ideas?

Cheers.

Comment: Not in any sort of programmatically reliable way. Whatever 'rules' you come up with, there will be plenty of false positives. If you decide that a code that connect to an external domain and sends data is malicious, then google analytics would be considered malicious. Or many banner ads (which may/may not be malicious). Best you could hope is to 'flag for manual review'.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can notice terms like iframe, http request, or something similar.

But once obfuscation, it's really hard to find out. You can do a step-by-step execution on firebug, and try to figure out what every line is doing.

Then you'll need perception to anticipate any result.